# Merging two jQuery selections

Tags: jquery

```
var _sel1 = $('.red');
var _sel2 = $('.yellow');
```

How can I merge them into one, without using different selectors?

```
// I don't want to do it this way 
var _sel3=$('.red,.yellow') or $('.red').add('.yellow');
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
var _sel3 = _sel1.add(_sel2);
```

Comment: okie i got it , i was not aware of the fact that we can pass some variable to ".add()" to add to current selection.
it worked thanx.