# Merge js commands togther

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not an expert in JavaScript so I don't know how to put this together, but basically:

I want to `addClass` and `attr disabled` to `$submit` & `$inputs`. I did it as follows:

```
$submit.addClass("sent");
$submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$inputs.addClass("sent");
$inputs.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

The issue is, I was trying to simplify the script above by having them all in one command "don't know what it is called", so I tried:

```
$submit, $input.addClass("sent");
```

But that only worked for `$input` and `$submit` has been ignored, I am not really an expert in JavaScript and I did not know what to search for to find a solution.

Question is, can I merge both `$submit` and `$input` together?

Comment: exact duplicate of [Merging two jQuery selections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400797/merging-two-jquery-selections)

Comment: @user1066946 again, I do NOT know what it was called, so really did not know what to search for...

Comment: Its Ok - I just flagged it as a duplicate, that's nothing to worry about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$submit.add($inputs).addClass('sent').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

This will allow you to combine collections of elements together and then run whatever other jQuery code you want on the new combined collection.

Comment: So basically add acts like AND?

Comment: No, it groups selector collections together.

Comment: Correct. What it literally means is "Take the `$submit` collection of elements and add the `$inputs` collection of elements to it"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/) to achieve what you want.

Just try,

```
$submit.add($input).addClass("sent").prop('disabled', true);
```

and additionally use

```
.prop('disabled', true)
```

instead of using

```
.attr('disabled','disabled')
```

Comment: Can I know the reason for up voting the other answer even though I explored this idea first.? Any mistakes with my answers.?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a slection including all your target elements with [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/), and then use chaining to call multiple methods on the selected elements, leaving you with this one liner...

```
$submit.add($inputs).addClass("sent").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you do this -

```
$('input, submit').addClass('sent').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

However, for disabling attributes you should use prop() in the newer versions of jQuery.

Comment: So do not use disabled?

Comment: No, disabled is fine. You'd use prop() (http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of attr()

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use an array of elements and pass to a function like this:

```
function disableEvent(arr) {
    for (var i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
        arr[i].addClass('sent');
        arr[i].attr('disabled','disabled');
    }

}
//calling function
disableEvent([$submit,$inputs]);
```