# jQuery selector - get <select> element only if <option> is not disabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm looking for a jQuery selector that would return the `<select>` element only if the `<option>` selected is NOT disabled.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <select name="input-select">
        <option disabled selected>Select an option</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Now, if you run this jQuery selector:

```
$("form select option:selected:not([disabled])")
```

it will either return `[]` if the disabled option is select, or either return the `<option>` selected.
I need to get the `<select>` element return, i know i could be using `.parent()`, but i can't use it for some reason in my code.

Also

```
$("form select option:selected:not([disabled]):parent")
```

Doesn't return the parent, i though `:parent` was there for that?

EDIT:
That may help you guys to understand my goal:

```
$.each($("form").find("input[name], textarea[name], select[name] option:selected:not([disabled]):parent"), function(index, value) {
    console.log(value.name+"="+value.value);
});
```

So, i just want to return every "input" element of a form, only if they are valuable for me

Comment: I've never heard of `:parent`.  And you can't use `.parent()`?  Have you tried `.closest('select')`?

Comment: @bowheart well, let's say i just can't use any function, i need to have it done by selector. this selector is chained with other selector. like $("input, textarea"), so if i apply .parent() i won't have the input or textarea element anymore but their parents...

Comment: I'd suggest two separate questions for two topic areas.  You seem to have one question for combined CSS selectors and another on the `:parent` predicate.

Comment: See the following for `:parent`. http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/   It is satisfied if the current element has > 0 children.  There is NO CSS to navigate up the tree ... see http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with one selector, so we need to use `.add()`, like [Kolban said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27239889/901641):

```
var selection = $("form").find("input[name], textarea[name]");
selection.add($("form").find("select[name] option:selected:not([disabled])").parent())
```

Answer (score 4):

How about using the following code to determine it:

```
var selectedOption = $("select option:selected");

if(selectedOption.is(":enabled"))
{
    var parentObject = selectedOption.parent();
    console.log(parentObject);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjt09amw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query example that will find options that are selected but not disabled:

```
$("form select option[selected]:not(option[disabled])")
```

This can be tested/demonstrated with the following code fragment:

```
$(function(){
    $("form select option[selected]:not(option[disabled])").each(function(i, e) {
        console.log("Item: %O -> %s", e, e.outerHTML);
    });
    console.log("Done!");
});
```

If one wishes to find the containing `<select>`, the following may be used:

An illustrative [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/e42zev0u/1/) has been provided.

```
$("form select option[selected]:not(option[disabled])").parent("select")
```

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/e42zev0u/2/) for this has also been provided.

Comment: This return the option element, i need to get the select element returned.

Comment: "i know i could be using .parent(), but i can't use it for some reason in my code.", check my edit on the question, you may understand why

Comment: That is a pretty vague.  Can you clarify what "some reason" might be?

Comment: I'm selecting other element at the same time, if i add .parent(), i'm getting the select element, but not the other element i'm selecting at the same time, check the edited question, Thanks

Comment: Run two separate selections and then combine them.  See the following:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400797/merging-two-jquery-selections